# Being able to select text with zoom?

Tags: html, css, d3.js, svg

I have an svg that has elements with text in them. I want to be able to select this text, which I'm able to do, unless I add zooming:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
              inner.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" +
                                          "scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
            });
        svg.call(zoom);
```

What are the necessary Javascript/HTML/CSS changes I have to make in order to have the text selectable?

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm not familiar with what UAs are, but in terms of browser bugs, I think this was a design choice. I'm using Firefox, and my inspector displays `moz-user-select: none;` when I start dragging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some event competition going on here.  The zoom/pan events are at a higher level and are eating the text selection on the text.  To set things right, stop the event propagation when you interact with the text element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var width = 500,
      height = 500;

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 10])
      .on("zoom", zoomed);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .call(zoom)
      .append("g");

    svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", 250)
      .attr("y", 250)
      .text("This is some text.")
      .on("mousedown", function() {
        d3.event.stopPropagation();
      });

    function zoomed() {
      svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    }
  </script>
```